# Netbeans 7: JVM Creation Failed, which settting to change in netbeans.conf (windows)?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7

I was having an issue with JVM Creation Failed when executing Netbeans in Windows, and after looking around i found 2 parameters that can fix the issue.

But i am unsure which to use, both fix the problem...

Can anyone tell me the difference and advise which i should be changing..

```
-J-Xmx512m

or

-J-XX:MaxPermSize=128m
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly answer to your question, but might help too:

1. If you are running for example Win 7 64bit and 32bit Java JDK, try to install 64bit JDK, it helps many people.
2. Another one solution, is to delete created temporary folders, which contain the file splash.PNG (in NB folder in Doc and Settings folder).
3. And maybe this can help too, close any opened PDFs in Adobe Reader (version 9 probably). I get this error more often while running the built app from NB IDE and running some PDF triggers this problem.

Comment: +1: I get this problem when Visual Studio 2010 or Firefox are launched

Comment: Unfortunately closing those applications is not a solution....64/32 bit problem may be the case indeed...also [Bug 211035 - jvm creation failed in neatbeans 7.1.1](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=211035)